# Menu not accessible when new workbook has been created

Tags: excel, vba

Within my code, I have to create a new workbook and paste data into it for people to then save to their personal hard drive. When I'm debugging, for some reason, the menu isn't available unless you click off the workbook, then click it again. Has anyone seen this before and how did you fix it?

The code starts with a button press and it pops up a userform. I have the userform unloading at the end of the code because I thought it was getting in the way, but it didn't help.

If anyone knows how to allow access to the menu immediately, I would appreciate any help. I don't want to have to tell people to click off excel to be able to save.

Comment: What menu is not visible ?

Comment: Assuming the menu is a user form? Show your code and maybe the community can try help debug the issue.From my knowledge, using `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` should bring the user form to the front at the beginning.